# How is make oldconfig in linux kernel compilation able to detect there are new features to be configured?

Tags: build, compilation, makefile, linux-kernel

We know that to build a new custom kernel on the existing old kernel we have to run 'make oldconfig' first. This command will ask us about the new configuration options added in the current release. How the things work exactly here. I mean how one can say in general that a feature is new in the kernel.

Comment: If it doesn't appear in the old `.config` file, including its commented out lines, then it is considered to be a new option. This can cause problems when options are renamed or otherwise reorganised, as the old settings of options that have been replaced may not be remembered for the replacement options.

Comment: Let us make the point clear. Say a new feature is added in a driver, under the flag CONFIG_XXX.  Now, we run "make oldconfig", say. How does kbuild decide to prompt whether to enable this feature or not "[N/y/?] (NEW)". Does it refer kconfig files.